# Add numbers in Column B based and on Day of the Week in Column A and display highest/lowest resulting Day

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that lists every day of the year and is updated on a daily basis. Next to each day is a percentage. I would like to display the day of the week that has the highest (and lowest) percentage when adding all relative days throughout the year. (i.e.: all Thursdays)

I am using this formula, which only partially works. It displays the day of the week, but seems to only reference the latest occurrence instead of all in Column A.

B2:
=iferror(INDEX($A4:$A,MATCH(MAX(B4:B),B4:B,0)),"")

B3:
=iferror(INDEX($A4:$A,MATCH(MIN(B4:B),B4:B,0)),"")

Link to a sample book: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_LP5MmmgW3i0zM6ziud9YrWfH5SvuHFbZH3OmRj9W6E/edit#gid=0

I hope this is enough information to understand what I am hoping to accomplish.. Is this possible in Google Sheets?

If I can get this to work my second goal would be to show the highest/lowest for the current month (or a specific month) in addition to the whole year.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the shared spreadsheet and see if it does what you want.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LL4Mgn_IWa-8W6Q0TythdMhBieVFt8ZiKI_UeO9ciTI/edit?usp=sharing

Added col L,O,R,and U for numeric day of week, current month, 
current year, and month number. You can hide these columns. 
I added some data for testing.